# R execution issue - No function found corresponding to methods exports from 'Runuran' for: 'initialize', 'show'

Tags: r, rscript

I am trying to run an Rscript. Each time it throws a warning message:

> "no function found corresponding to methods exports from 'Runuran' for: 'initialize', 'show'"

while loading the package `Runuran`, and execution gets halted with the following error message -

> Error in initialize(value, ...) : 
>     cannot use object of class "character" in new():  class "unuran" does not extend that class Calls: urweibull -> new -> initialize -> initialize
>   Execution halted

I would really appreciate any help that I could get. I am using R-3.2.1

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but this just happened to me for `bioconductor::GEOquery`.

This occurs because `Runuran` exports methods named `initialize` and `show`. There are functions with these names within the package `methods` and `Runuran` is trying to turn those functions into generic methods (as described in the secion on "creating new methods and generics" in Hadley Wickham's ["OO field guide"](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#s4)). It is failing to do this, because `methods::initialize` and `methods::show` are not visible in your `Rscript` run.

In an R session, `methods` is attached at bootup, but it is not attached automatically when you run `Rscript`. (Compare the 'attached base packages' when calling `sessionInfo()` within Rscript and R). At least, this is the case up to R-3.4.2.

A simple fix is to add `library(methods)` into your script or to call your script using `Rscript -e "library(methods); source(<script_name>)"`